Angular - @ViewChild with component variable
I am rendering the same component on two different Router routes. Since it is one component both instances would have the same template reference variable. It seems like that create a problem that is outside of this post, however, to test it, I want to have two different reference variables for the templates. so, I am thinking to use component variables for reference variables. Something like this:
@ViewChild(unique_var)

Is it even possible? Any idea?
Update. Here is my template:
<div fxFlexFill>
  <div
      class="some_class"
      #achart
      >
  </div>
</div

Thanks

Please show your template code. It's not clear what you are asking.

Template variables are scoped so there's a chance you don't need to do anything fancy. We'd need to see your template to be able to help. Please edit your question to add more details?

Updated the question.

Could you include the Routes configuration and complete component ts+html for further clarification? Note if you render same component on different routes, Angular still destroys your component when navigating from one route to another. Only when staying on same route (but with different parameters), Angular would not destroy the component. (This is the default route reuse strategy in Angular). Please include in full your problem description to understand what you need to achieve. Make sure to include a code which is working for you, e.g. a stackblitz so we can run what you run.

The simple amswer is not to reuse same component on two routes if you are not rendering exactly same information. I noticed your other questions on this subject, it seems you are actually searching for a way of sharing state between your components in the app.
You are better off with creating a service and store there your information in an observable exposed by that service.
Or use ngrx for this.
Read more for example here as a starting point: https://medium.com/@salem.naser.elashry/techniques-to-manage-state-in-angular-bf4739533977

Thank you for taking time and looking into this. Yes, you are correct, I am using same component on two different routes. I am also using router reuse strategy to keep all component states. The component is a massive screen with a Highcharts chart as a center piece. It is very interactive and might many different scenarios. The user needs to go other screens and get back to this one to the same state. Everything works like a charm, except the chart. Seems like because of using container that holds charts on both routes with a hardcoded template reference. Which is shown in my post.

The Highcharts engineers are advising me to try different template variables before they get involved. And that is what I am trying to do.

Why don't you add your code (stripped down to a runnable sample) on a separate question under both highcharts and angular tags? I see other questions for Highcharts on Stackoverflow. This may be a quirk of Highcharts with a known answer.

Did you try without any template reference at all in the html? Then use @ViewChild(HighchartsChartComponent) to obtain your component in TS code. But the real question here is about chart instances, if you will have one chart instance or more. If you want to reuse everything, I suppose you need to make sure only one chart instance is created.
